# NetworkOnMainThreadException in the flatMap

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

I'm new in `rxjava` or rxandroid and I want to change my `AsyncTask` and callback hell to `observable` and `subscriber`. But I have a problem with that. I need to do two request to my database.

My response from the first request will be a result for second request. I try to resolve this with `flatMap`. First request return value and everything is ok, but next request give me `NetworkOnMainThreadException`.

I know that request execute on the `main thread` but why? I try to add `subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())` before `flatMap` but result is the same. Could you help me with that and explain what am I  doing wrong? Thanks in advance. my code......

```
private void getFavouriteList(){
    Observable.create((Observable.OnSubscribe<PaginatedScanList<UserDO>>) subscriber -> {
        final Map<String, AttributeValue> filterExpressionAttributeValues = new HashMap<>();
        filterExpressionAttributeValues
                .put(":val1", new AttributeValue().withS(sharedPreferences.getString("socialId", "")));
        final DynamoDBScanExpression scanExpression = new DynamoDBScanExpression()
                .withFilterExpression("socialId = :val1")
                .withExpressionAttributeValues(filterExpressionAttributeValues);
        PaginatedScanList<UserDO> result = dynamoDBMapper.scan(UserDO.class, scanExpression);
        Log.d(TAG, "first result size " + result.size());
        subscriber.onNext(result);
        subscriber.onCompleted();
    })
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .filter(result -> {
                if(result.isEmpty()) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Can not find user", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            })
            .flatMap(user -> Observable.from(user.get(0).getFavourites()))
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .flatMap(result -> {
                final Map<String, AttributeValue> filterExpressionAttributeValues = new HashMap<>();
                filterExpressionAttributeValues
                        .put(":val1", new AttributeValue().withS(result));
                filterExpressionAttributeValues
                        .put(":val2", new AttributeValue().withN("1"));
                final DynamoDBScanExpression scanExpression = new DynamoDBScanExpression()
                        .withFilterExpression("productId = :val1 and selling = :val2")
                        .withExpressionAttributeValues(filterExpressionAttributeValues);
                PaginatedScanList<ProductDO> res = dynamoDBMapper.scan(ProductDO.class, scanExpression);
                Log.d(TAG, "second result size " + res.size());
                return Observable.from(res);
            })
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<ProductDO>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {
                    favouriteProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    favouriteProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(ProductDO productDO) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "productId " + productDO.getProductId());
                    product.add(productDO);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/how-to-fix-android-os-networkonmainthreadexception

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move your `.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())` to just before your subscribe.

PS: You should not be using `Observable.create()` unless there's no other alternative.

Edited to fix the Toast in the filter issue.

```
private void getFavouriteList(){
    Observable.create((Observable.OnSubscribe<PaginatedScanList<UserDO>>) subscriber -> {
        final Map<String, AttributeValue> filterExpressionAttributeValues = new HashMap<>();
        filterExpressionAttributeValues
                .put(":val1", new AttributeValue().withS(sharedPreferences.getString("socialId", "")));
        final DynamoDBScanExpression scanExpression = new DynamoDBScanExpression()
                .withFilterExpression("socialId = :val1")
                .withExpressionAttributeValues(filterExpressionAttributeValues);
        PaginatedScanList<UserDO> result = dynamoDBMapper.scan(UserDO.class, scanExpression);
        Log.d(TAG, "first result size " + result.size());
        subscriber.onNext(result);
        subscriber.onCompleted();
    })
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .filter(result -> {
                if(result.isEmpty()) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Can not find user", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            })
            .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .flatMap(user -> Observable.from(user.get(0).getFavourites()))
            .flatMap(result -> {
                final Map<String, AttributeValue> filterExpressionAttributeValues = new HashMap<>();
                filterExpressionAttributeValues
                        .put(":val1", new AttributeValue().withS(result));
                filterExpressionAttributeValues
                        .put(":val2", new AttributeValue().withN("1"));
                final DynamoDBScanExpression scanExpression = new DynamoDBScanExpression()
                        .withFilterExpression("productId = :val1 and selling = :val2")
                        .withExpressionAttributeValues(filterExpressionAttributeValues);
                PaginatedScanList<ProductDO> res = dynamoDBMapper.scan(ProductDO.class, scanExpression);
                Log.d(TAG, "second result size " + res.size());
                return Observable.from(res);
            })
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<ProductDO>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {
                    favouriteProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    favouriteProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(ProductDO productDO) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "productId " + productDO.getProductId());
                    product.add(productDO);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: Thaks, it's really help. What is the problem with `Observable.create()`?

Comment: It's really easy to make a mistake using `Observable.create()`. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/rx-java/1418/observable/4633/create-an-observable#t=201701131129135582063) for documentation on alternatives.

Comment: There is another problem when I place `.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())` before subscribe, the `Toast` in the filter doesn't work. It's give me `android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException`

Comment: The second `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())` is unnecessary and has no practical effects other than wasting a thread.